# Redundant prototype parameter specification in ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

The [ctypes function `prototype` specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-function-prototypes) says

> The first item is an integer containing a combination of direction flags for the parameter: [...]
>
> 4: Input parameter which defaults to the integer zero.

and shortly after,

> The optional third item is the default value for this parameter.

Why does "type 4" exist when the exact same thing, seemingly, can be specified by writing `0` in the third tuple element? Are they indeed equivalent? Why would one be preferred over the other?

In fact, there's some evidence that they aren't equivalent: if I define [WlanRegisterNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanregisternotification) like

```
proto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,

    ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
    ctypes.wintypes.BOOL,
    WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK,
    ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID,
    ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
)
fun = proto(
    ('WlanRegisterNotification', wlanapi),
    (
        (IN, 'hClientHandle'),
        (IN, 'dwNotifSource'),
        (IN, 'bIgnoreDuplicate'),
        (IN | DEFAULT_ZERO, 'funcCallback'),
        (IN | DEFAULT_ZERO, 'pCallbackContext'),
        (IN | DEFAULT_ZERO, 'pReserved'),
        (OUT, 'pdwPrevNotifSource'),
    ),
)
```

It behaves nonsensically when passed values for the first four parameters:

```
TypeError: call takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Why should it assume that there are exactly three arguments, when arguments four, five and six are given defaults (but should accept explicit values)? Removing `DEFAULT_ZERO` and adding `, None` solves the problem, but is not a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DEFAULT_ZERO` seems to mean "don't pass a parameter...use a default as input", so it only makes sense to use for `pReserved`.  The other two parameters need valid defaults.  Note that `int(0)` is not a valid default for a callback, and `None` raises `expected WinFunctionType instance instead of NoneType`, so I passed a default null instance of the notification callback type.

Functional example:

```py
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes

PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA = ctypes.c_void_p
WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(None, PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA, ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID)

null_callback = WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK()

# valid callback
@WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK
def callback(param1, param2):
    print(param1, param2)

IN = 1
OUT = 2
DEFAULT_ZERO = 4

wlanapi = ctypes.WinDLL('wlanapi')

proto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,

    ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
    ctypes.wintypes.BOOL,
    WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK,
    ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID,
    ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
)

fun = proto(
    ('WlanRegisterNotification', wlanapi),
    (
        (IN, 'hClientHandle'),
        (IN, 'dwNotifSource'),
        (IN, 'bIgnoreDuplicate'),
        (IN, 'funcCallback', null_callback),
        (IN, 'pCallbackContext', None),
        (IN | DEFAULT_ZERO, 'pReserved'),
        (OUT, 'pdwPrevNotifSource'),
    ),
)
fun.errcheck = lambda result, func, args: (result, args[5])
print(fun(0,0,0))
print(fun(0,0,0,callback))
print(fun(0,0,0,callback,None))
print(fun(0,0,0,callback,None,None))  # this will fail. pReserved can't be passed.
```

Output (note that `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87` since I passed garbage params, but it makes it passed ctypes parameter validation):

```
(87, 0)
(87, 0)
(87, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(fun(0,0,0,callback,None,None))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: call takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)
```

Frankly I avoid *paramFlags* and use `.argtypes` and `.restype` to declare arguments and return type and write wrappers to make the C API exactly the way I want it if needed:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA = ct.c_void_p
WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK = ct.WINFUNCTYPE(None, PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA, w.LPVOID)

null_callback = WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK()

# valid callback
@WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK
def callback(param1, param2):
    print(param1, param2)

wlanapi = ct.WinDLL('wlanapi')
wlanapi.WlanRegisterNotification.argtypes = w.HANDLE, w.DWORD, w.BOOL, WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK, w.LPVOID, w.LPVOID, ct.POINTER(w.DWORD)
wlanapi.WlanRegisterNotification.restype = w.DWORD

def fun(h, src, ignore, cb=null_callback, context=None):
    prev = w.DWORD()
    result = wlanapi.WlanRegisterNotification(h, src, ignore, cb, context, None, ct.byref(prev))
    return result, prev.value

print(fun(0, 0, 0))
print(fun(0, 0, 0, callback))
print(fun(0, 0, 0, callback, None))
print(fun(0, 0, 0, callback, None, None))  # this will fail. pReserved can't be passed.
```

Comment: _don't pass a parameter...it will be zero always_ is basically what I've found out through trial and error. I suppose the documentation on that value is less than clear.

Comment: The source code in `_ctypes` has a more descriptive comment: `['in', 'lcid'] parameter. Always taken from defval,if given, else the integer 0.` (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d7a788332666eabade922bf5d976df8c362ecb14/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L3900) And this also matches the implemented behavior.